# Concurrent connections in signalR hub

Tags: angularjs, chat, signalr-hub

I have o chat application made with angular and signalR 2.

I have a problem when I try to connect simultaneous more then 5 user an application in same browser (Chrome).

On the sixth connection I see in Chrome console next text:

```
[17:14:09 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'chat'.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.js:76 [17:14:09 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chat%22%7D%5D&clientProtocol=1.3'.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.js:76 [17:14:09 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://localhost:49386/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectio…Q13E%2Fb5FgfyojlL&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chat%22%7D%5D&tid=3'.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.js:76 [17:14:09 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource connected.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.js:76 [17:14:09 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332 and a connection lost timeout of 20000.
jquery.signalR-2.0.2.js:76 [17:14:12 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)] SignalR: Invoking chat.LoginClient
```

And it's waiting until I close a tab with opened connection. After that, it's execute chat.LoginClient, but the System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected() not firing for the user which had close the browser tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer from other forum: http://forums.asp.net/p/2039166/5875383.aspx?Concurrent+connections+problem+in+signalR+hub